# how to update html with translate pipe in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In ionic 3 I am creating one pipe called `translate` and in HTML I am using it like `{{'welcome'|translate}}`

### translate.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'translate',
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform 
{
    transform(value: string, ...args) 
    {
        var lang = localStorage.getItem("default-app-lang");
        return this[lang](value);
    }
    en(key)
    {
        var lang = 
        {
            "welcome":"welcome",
        }

        return lang[key];
    }
    gu(key)
    {
        var lang = 
        {
            "welcome":"વેલકોમ",
        }
        return lang[key];
    }
}
```

translation working fine but I am not getting an idea to how to update HTML when user change their language `without closing and without restart application`

Comment: well.. depends on when you want to change it.. you could take the `lang` variable as second parameter of the pipe

Comment: No, i think you are getting me. That is working fine but take an example like in one form I am displaying Hello with translate pipe and one lang dropdown English, French now Hello is in English how can I change is it french because a pipe is already loaded with their content.